# wrapping TCL/TK file with AWK command inside

Tags: linux, awk, tcl, tk-toolkit

I've created a simple TCL/TK file which contains a button which executes awk command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env wish
package require Tk
pack [button .b -text "process" -command {exec awk {$1=="aa" {print $0}} ./input.txt > ./temp.txt}]
```

Using freewrap I made this file executable on Windows (.exe) and when I push the button I have such an error:

Error: couldn't execute "awk": no such file or directory

Is there a way to include/add awk into .exe output file or attach awk libraires to .exe as external file or other way to make awk command recognized without rewriting awk command on TCL code?

Regards

Comment: Calling an external program creates an external dependency? Oh noes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The awk-code you showed here is quite simple and can easily be rewritten in tcl.

But you want to know a solution without this, so you need to install an awk exe on your computer. 
One may find an executable here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm

Comment: I don't know why but I've installed it and I have the same error. Moreover awk command is not recognized even from cmd termianl... Is there no other way to do it without instalation for example adding somehow awk dll libraries to .exe file like TCL packages?

Comment: do you call it as "gawk" (I don't have Windows but I think the program name is gawk.exe)

Comment: yes, the same info: 'gawk' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Here is my last guess: (g)awk.exe is not installed in your $PATH environment (sorry: %PATH%). Try C:\programs\gnu\gawk.exe (or whereever it is installed). If this works you can either add the install path to %PATH% or call it with full path in your tcl program.

Comment: working!:) I did copy of awk.exe and put it in one folder with my .exe file and then in the command for tcl/tk button I put {exec **awk.exe** {$1=="aa" {print... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
awk {$1=="aa" {print $0}} ./input.txt > ./temp.txt
```

in Tcl:

```
set in [open ./input.txt r]
set out [open ./temp.txt w]
while {[gets $in line] != -1} {
    set firstword [lindex [split [string trim $line]] 0]
    # or: regexp {\S+} $line firstword
    if {$firstword eq "aa"} {puts $out $line}
}
close $in
close $out
```